# Copy all bridge traffic to a specific interface

Tags: networking, security, network-monitoring, network-bridge

I have a bridge/switch set up an a machine that has multiple ports. Occasionally, I have a vm running through virtualbox, and I'll have it use a virtual adapter and then I add the adapter to the bridge. I have heard that some switches can copy all the traffic they see to a specific port on the bridge, usually for network monitoring. I would like to be able to run some windows based network tools. I do not want to run Windows on the actual hardware, because it would be lots of work to duplicate my setup in windows, so I was thinking if I can copy all traffic to a port, I can send it to a VM with windows. How can I set this up? I think this might be ebtables area, but I don't know ebtables well enough to know for sure, and it always seems like (from my understanding of ebtables) ebtables does something with the traffic (drop, accept, etc), but never copies it.

Comment: I'm not clear on what your switch is.  Is this an external switch, or a bridge internal to your VM box?  What's the vendor?   This kind of traffic mirroring is what Cisco would call SPAN, though other vendors have other names for it.

Comment: The bridge I mentioned is a software one, running directly (not in a VM) on the hardware of a desktop. So I guess I would say the vendor is Linux in a way. It doesn't have anything to do with a VM (unless I plug a VM into it).

Comment: btw, if you use @username format it will inform them that they have a response when they log in.  There's a post in meta with more info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that [daemonlogger](http://packages.ubuntu.com/daemonlogger) [image: Install daemonlogger]
 will do want you want.

> It is capable of operating in two
>   modes: sniffing packets and  logging
>   them directly to disk (files are
>   automatically rolled over  after 1GB
>   of data), or in a "soft-tap" mode
>   where it mirrors packets  on another
>   interface.

It is is the repository, so `sudo apt-get install daemonlogger` will get you started.

Syntax would be similar to

```
sudo daemonlogger -i <input_interface> -o <mirror_interface>
```

where the arguments are explained as

```
   -i <interface>
   Set interface to grab data from to <interface>.

   -o <interface>
   Disable logging, instead mirror  traffic  from  -i  <interface>  to  -o
   <interface>.
```

The biggest caveat is that you need to make sure that the destination port is capable of receiving the retransmitted traffic.

If you need more specific configuration guidance, you'd need to give more details on your bridge and interface setup.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to simple in comparison to doing it with tc (which I can't seem to find much information on).

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this is possible with a Linux-based software bridge (at least, not in its current version). If it were, it should be an option in the [brctl](http://linux.die.net/man/8/brctl) utility.

Yes, many physical Ethernet switches have some kind of a mirroring/monitoring capability, which would allow you to designate an interface within the bridge to send *all* traffic to. It sounds like this would be a good enhancement for situations like yours.

**Edit**: you may be able to use a [traffic control](http://marc.info/?l=linux-netdev&m=128853067804910&w=2) rule to accomplish this.

Comment: I have to agree that this would seems like brctl's territory. I asked on the netfilter mailing list and they mentioned the same page you linked to about tc. Unfortunately, that page went way over my head. (I only started messing with tc about 2 days ago).